# Commit failed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to commit one java file in Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 using SVN

When I do Team/Commit on the file I get the following.

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File 'C:\Users\...\workspace\...\src\com\MyCode.java' is out of date
```

When I try and do Team/Update - whether on the file or the folder or the project, I get

```
Some resources were not updated.
svn: E175002: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default'
```

I have tried

1. Restarting Visual SVN Server
2. Deleting the .java file and then adding it again
3. Renaming the .java file, and then renaming it back
4. Updating the Eclipse and SVN software, and trying again
5. Team/Revert, Team/Update, making changes, Team/Commit

Can anyone help? (all other files/folders etc. work fine)

PS This question was copied from https://superuser.com/questions/585724/commit-failed-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just create another workspace, create a new subversion project and download the entire code base from subversion to this new workspace. Then hand copy the .java file over to the new workspace and try to check in. If it works abandon your old workspace.

Answer (score 2):

you should try a team/cleanup

In eclipse rt click the top level folder
click team -> cleanup

You probably have some .svn file lock you don't know about.

Another option would be to use the tortoise svn windows plugin if you have it.

[tortoise svn download site](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

This integrates great with windows and avoids eclipse subversion plugin problems.  I have found it to be a nice backup when eclipse acts up.

Comment: I did a Team/Cleanup but the problems are exactly the same!

Comment: Regarding Tortoise SVN. Should a one-time use of Tortoise SVN on one file solve the problems in Eclipse?

Comment: The tortoise svn solution is really just another subversion tool outside eclipse.  I only mentioned it as a way to possibly get around your issue entirely.  It would be another tool to use altogether. I don't know if it would experiance the same issues you describe above

Comment: I am sure you tried this, but you could also just create another workspace, create a new subversion project and download the entire code base from subversion to this new workspace.  Then hand copy the .java file over to the new workspace and try to check in.  If it works abandon your old workspace.

Comment: I didn't try this - it seemed like a lot of bother for one file... If things get worse then I will probably try it!

Comment: Eventually I did the "creating another workspace" solution spartikus (because I had to move the repository somewhere else) and it worked - if you want to post this as an answer - I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Commit through TortoiseSVN, it will suggest you to do an update, and then you will be able to commit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, 
For one folder I couldn't commit the files.
I checked each file and could find that the problem is happening with one file, that I deleted already. 
I went to the directory where the deleted file is and opened the entry file in the .svn folder within that directory.

I could see there was an entry for the deleted file and I deleted this entry and saved the file.

All works fine after.

So it will be better check in each individual file and find the one that causing this issue, then correct the entry or delete this file and recreate it.

Comment: I know the problematic file and the directory in which it lives. But I do not have a .svn folder within that directory. What folder are you suggesting and where is it?

Answer (score 0):

spartikus' answer should be marked as the answer.

I experienced the same commit failed message.  I had TortoiseSVN installed previously, but started using Eclipse's Subversive plugin.  In most cases it works fine, but I've run into issues like this where Tortoise is a good backup and solution.

After installing TortoiseSVN, you'll see these icons beside all your SVN files and folders.
[Tortoise Status Icons](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html)

To resolve your issue, open the location of your project folder inside Windows Explorer.  Select/Highlight the files that need to be committed, right click *'SVN Commit'*, enter your commit message and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

go to team synchronizing view of eclipse > right click on project > Local >cleanup should resolved this issue otherwise create a new work space

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i was also facing the same issue yesterday and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally run into this with both Eclipse CDT and Code Composer Studio (based on Eclipse). I found an easier way to fix this (at least it's easier for me):

I just open a terminal, navigate to the source path, then use the SVN command-line to update then commit. So far it's worked every time, and no need to add tools, recreate workspaces, etc. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the SVN Cleanup Command at your system Workspace Location. Right click on project location rightClick/ Tortois svn/ CleanUp/ Ok