# Eclipse-SVN plugin commit issue

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am using SVN plug with eclipse. when I try to commit the code, I get the following error.

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File 'C:\Users\anand_raj\Project details\EnterpriseSearchService\src\main\java\com\photon\knowledgemanagement\bean\Node.java' is out of date
```

I have also tried the following

1. Team CleanUp
2. Team update
3. Deleted the entire project and checked out the code again from SVN
4. Switched to a new workspace and checked out the code again from SVN
5. Googled and found this, but didn't help much: [Commit failed in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575504/commit-failed-in-eclipse)

Please help.

**P.S:** I am able to commit through **TortoiseSVN** but **not** through **Eclipse SVN-plugin**

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem occured in this topic
[How do you overcome the svn 'out of date' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87950/how-do-you-overcome-the-svn-out-of-date-error)
maybe you find the solution there. Since I can see in your code it says that Node.java is out of date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the link there talks about **TortoiseSvn** client. I am using **Eclipse SVN plugin**.